# *Within-country* Fertility vs. income

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, data-request

Any pointers to reviews or data-sets or meta-analyses looking at the relationship between household fertility rate and family income/wealth (possibly with other factors like education and geographical region also measured) ? I assume there is some US census data with these values ? Perhaps also from other countries ?